# How do you read /00/ in csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm using import csv to make an addressbook. I've done the part which searches for the surname using:

```
def surname():
     surname = input("Please enter a surname. ")

     with open("AB.csv", "rt") as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') 
          for row in reader:
               for field in column:
                   if field == surname:
                       print (column)
```

But now I need to search through the csv file for the date of birth. The user would need to type in something like /04/ and it prints out the row which have /04/ in it. I've kinda stumped on how to do it.

```
Jackson Samantha    2 Heather Row   Basingstoke RG21 3SD    01256 135434    23/04/1973  sam.jackson@hotmail.com
```

is an example.

Comment: In what way is searching for the date any different from searching for the surname?

Comment: Search in the field, so if its the 5th field `for row in reader: if field in row[4]:` etc.

Answer (score 0):

your CSV file format is wrong, try this:

```
"Jackson","Samantha",2,"Heather Row","Basingstoke","RG21","3SD",01256,135434,"23/04/1973","sam.jackson@hotmail.com"
```

---

```
with open("file.csv", "rt") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    for field in row:
        if field == surname:
            print(row[-2])
```

above code working until the date be on the penultimate (you can change the slice)

i hope these helps.